# Websocket FastAPI and React JS

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to use websockets with `FastAPI` and `React Js`.
The backend is written in Python. There is also a database (sqlalchemy) and some ML algorithms.

I want to actualize the results on the frontend when the processing of my ML pipeline is finished.

I have a React History page which displays all results.
Here is my websocket definition in React:

```
componentDidMount () {
        // Handle websocket opening
        this.webSocket.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Connected to websocket.")
        }
        // Handle message transmission
        this.webSocket.onmessage = event => {
            const response = JSON.parse(event.data)
            this.setState({ data: response })
            console.log(response)
        }
        // Handle websoket closing
        this.webSocket.onclose = () => {
            console.log("Disconnected.")
        }
    }
```

and this the FastAPI websocket defintion:

```
@app.websocket("/patients")
async def job_status_websocket(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await websocket.send_json(get_all_patients_results())
```

However, when launch the webapp, I get after few seconds this error:

```
[31mERROR[0m:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\websockets\websockets_impl.py", line 154, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 179, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 146, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 70, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 58, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 283, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 57, in app
    await func(session)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 228, in app
    await dependant.call(**values)
  File ".\api\server\server.py", line 111, in job_status_websocket
    await websocket.send_json(get_all_patients_results())
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 137, in send_json
    await self.send({"type": "websocket.send", "text": text})
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 68, in send
    await self._send(message)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\websockets\websockets_impl.py", line 212, in asgi_send
    await self.send(data)
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 555, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "c:\users\nlb\anaconda3\envs\ai_platform\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 812, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1005 (no status code [internal]), no reason
```

Comment: Hey Nicolas, Any update on this issue. How did u solve it? I'm stuck with a similar solution.

Comment: I am seeing the same error. @HackersInside were you able to fix this?